# Automatically reload Java AppEngine Maven project after making changes

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, maven

Is it possible to automatically reload a Java AppEngine project (which uses Maven) after making changes to the code? I.e. after making a change to the code (such as a JSP) I'd like to see those changes straight away in a web browser without having to re-run the project. Is this possible?

I have done the following:

1. Created a Maven project using the [Google's tutorial](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/introduction)
2. Imported it into Eclipse using [Google's instructions](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/eclipse#Importing_a_Maven_Project).
3. Enabled the "Build Automatically" setting on my project in Eclipse (which [this article](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/maven) suggests is required).
4. Run the dev server inside the ear project (mvm appengine:devserver)

However, changes to JSPs aren't automatically reflected when I view the page in a web browser. I can only see the changes by installing (mvn clean install) and then re-running the dev server.

Projects created using the Google Eclipse plugin reload automatically however, I'd prefer to use Maven as it'll make it easier to install other software (such as the Spring Framework).

Comment: I have the same question/issue. One thing that helps, is to run (on a separate command line) `mvn install` without stop/restarting the devserver - which will redeploy any changes it detects automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the `mvn install` tip! Try `mvn war:war` - it works and it's faster too (without having to rerun all the phases preceding install).

Answer (score 0):

I think I've got to the bottom of this:

1. Import **only the web Maven project** (not the main project) into Eclipse (as suggested in the [Eclipse Web Tools documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/webtoolsplatform#importing_an_existing_maven_project))
2. Create a server as per [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/eclipse#Running_the_Project). The web site should automatically reload 15 seconds after you make a change to the code. To change this...
3. Open the "servers" tab, right-click on your server and select "open".
4. Expand the "Publishing" section and decrease the value for "Automatically public after a build event.

[image: Publishing settings]

Note: the "auto scan for resources change setting" doesn't seem to make any difference.